# EXE mit Parameter mithilfe von PSEXEC starten

Tags: psexec

Good Morning,

maybe someone from you can help me with my problem.

On a server i want to run an .exe with PSEXEC. Furthermore i want to give the .exe an argument: /file.

`psexec.exe "\\SRV\C$\x\y\z\EXE\XYZ.exe" /file "\\SRV\C$\x\y\z\TEMP\*.xlsx" -WAIT`

Am Thankful for every reply.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with using admin credentials.